# i want dnn to email me when someone registers on my site

Tags: dotnetnuke

i want to have my dnn portal send me and another person an email whenever someone registers as a user.

can someone tell me how to get this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure the following:

1. Make sure that you have a valid SMTP server defined in your Host Settings > Advanced Settings in DNN.
2. Ensure that your user account is set as the site's administrator, which you can verify in Admin Settings > Advanced Settings > Other Settings.
3. Ensure the registration is not set to "None" (also under Admin Settings > Advanced Settings).

Comment: i have the smtp set already, my account is admin, where in the portal can i confif dnn to send email notifications to email addresses i supply when a registration occures???

Comment: for eaxmple when you register i want dnn to send an email to a@a.com and b@b.com after you create a registration.

Comment: The only way to do that is either with a custom registration module (DataSprings makes a good one), or by creating a user with an email address that you assign as the admin, and have that email address forward to the multiple addresses you want the notifications to go to.